# Procedure can't compile when dblink in body

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, dblink

I have problem with procedure that use dblinks

i have two databases one

One with

> Oracle 11.2.0.3

Second with

> Oracle 12c

On the second i created dblink to first one

and query

```
select max(id_pat) from patient@dest_pat;
```

works

but when i try to run

> 

```
 create or replace procedure trans_pat is
>     
>     begin
>           select max(id_pat) from patient@dest_pat;
>     end trans_pat;
```

it can't end in sqldeveloper

after canceling task from sql developer error appears

> ORA-00604:

Adding INTO variable doesn't change situation

only removing @dblink makes query complete with error but complete

[image]

Comment: That's not a valid statement within a PL/SQL block. The error you should be getting is PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement. You would need to declare a variable and do SELECT MAX(ID_PAT) INTO <variable name> FROM...

Comment: previously i had with INTO but i removed to make it simpler when i remove dblink i get error PLS-00428 but with dblink i cant get any error just waiting and waiting

Comment: Check if the below links helps . http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00604_error_occurred_and_recursive_sql_level_string.htm

Comment: It waits forever (how long?) when you try to create the procedure, or when you try to execute it? Can you do something like `select * from dual@dest_pat;` successfully, indicating the link itself is OK?

Comment: @Alex Poole mean more than 15min without result when select * from dual@dest_pat; works without problem

Comment: @Raj_Te error 

    ORA-00604:
i get after canceling task but it can be missleading i compiled all objects and only few views didnt compile

Comment: The above article say "DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH package " must compile to overcome ORA-00604: Can you check if the pkg is in compiled state.

Comment: @Raj_Te DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH is compiled and valid

Comment: Can you reply @Alex Pool question. How much time it takes to just execute select * from dual@dest_pat;   Just wanted to check if the link is working fine. And if its working fine then the issue is with you network bandwidth. Check the below link for more info and contact your network team. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_dblink_performance.htm  ..Alternatively you can give a try with HINT "DRIVING_SITE"

Comment: @Raj_Te - from the question the problem is at compilation time, not run time; and network shouldn't really affect an aggregate. Possibly the package definition is locked by another session but don't see how. Think this might be one for Oracle Support. Maybe I'd try running utlrp first, or looking for locks, but it doesn't seem to be something obvious.

Comment: @Raj_Te select * from dual@dest_pat works immediately , running create procedure with this select never ends, i just cancel it thru sqldeveloper gui,

Comment: @Kalmar can you please try with HINT 'Driving_Site' once. Lets see if this works else as mentioned earlier, you really have to check on the network bandwidth side. Also I guess what Alex is stating is making sense

Comment: I think the hint would only affect execution, not compilation. Can you recompile the produce with the query commented out and replaced with `null;` so it does nothing; or querying local dual instead - that would take the DB link out of the picture. And also maybe try compiling it through SQL\*Plus, just in case the version of SQL Developer you're using has a problem?

Comment: @Alex Poole i added gif to post to ilustrate, adding into idPat doesnt change anything and i waited 15min but it didnt